# Is there a maintenance mode in Wordpress core?

Tags: plugins, maintenance, offline

If I want to put a Wordpress (3.2.1) site into Maintenance mode, is it still necessary to use a plugin? If so, is [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/) a good option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is. But it is primarily meant for short interruptions (such as during upgrades) and not very user-friendly. WP creates `.maintenance` file in root (with timestamp info about time) to trigger it and removes after it is done.

See [WordPress Maintenance Mode Without a Plugin](http://sivel.net/2009/06/wordpress-maintenance-mode-without-a-plugin/) for reference.

In practice using a plugin is usually more convenient and functional.

Answer (score 2):

There is no maintenance mode in core AFAIK.
And as far as plugin's go, I prefer [JF3 Maintenance Redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jf3-maintenance-mode/) as it allows IP address whitelisting.